# iTunes Connect - Waiting for review

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

I uploaded a new version of my app and it's still waiting for review. It has been 10 days since I uploaded the binary.

I uploaded a full version of the same app the same day I uploaded the new version of the free app. The full version changed its status to Ready for sale three days ago (it took seven days to finish the review). The new version is not even "in review".

Seven days for new app and 10 days (so far) for a new version. I was wondering... Is this normal?

Comment: You can check out average review times in http://appreviewtimes.com, but generally, review time is inconsistent. I'm pretty sure that there is nothing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Completely usual. 
But normally it's the other way around, so updates are reviewed faster than new app binaries.
You can just sit down and relax ;)

Comment: "so updates are reviewed faster than new app binaries" But my update is taking more time than the new app binary

Comment: Yeah as I sad "normally". But seriously, just sit and wait. If it is not reviewed after 2 weeks reject the new binary and reupload it

Answer (score 0):

This happens sometimes - app review is pretty inconsistent. In my experience delays are a sign of app rejection but even that doesn't always hold true.

It's pretty much a crapshoot.